# What’s the probability of 101 heads over non-consecutive tosses?

Tags: probability

Imagine there’s this guy flipping a coin every day at every hour and I occasionally pass by him and record the tosses. The first 100 times the tosses are ALL heads. OK that’s weird but it’s guaranteed the coin is perfectly balanced.

Now what’s the probability the 101st time I pass by I will observe an head again? Is it really just 0.5?

Comment: What did you ask? You were saying about non consecutive events and finally asked something totally unrelated.

Comment: OK I tried to edit the question. Let me know if now it’s clear

Comment: If you insist that the coin is fair, then the only possible conclusion—assuming nothing sneaky is going on—is that the final toss comes up heads with probability $1/2$. But I, for one, would at least be pretty suspicious.

Comment: @BrianTung Wouldn’t you be suspicious because you expect the probability to be much lower than 1/2? I would and bet against another head indeed

Comment: If you do that, then you are not guaranteed that the coin is fair. You can't have it both ways. Either you're somehow guaranteed that the coin is fair (in which case the probability is $1/2$), or else the coin is actually leaning toward heads (in which case the coin is by definition unfair). ETA: Obviously, in a real life situation, I wouldn't trust that guarantee any further than I could toss it. But if we interpret this in a "mathematics problem" sort of way, then the history is irrelevant, assuming independent tosses, and if the coin is absolutely known to be fair, the probability is $1/2$.

Comment: Why history is relevant if tosses are consecutive instead?

Comment: History is never relevant. A coin is someting passive ; a coin does not remember the results of previous tosses. A coin will not think and decide : Last results were HHHHHHH, so I should now give T.

Comment: @Lourrran You’re giving T because T is now more likely to show?

Comment: You consider that the information 'All 100 previous tosses were H' , this information should influence te probability for next toss. Probably, you consider that next toss has a high probability to give T, because we are supposed to have same number of T and H. You consider : the coin has a memory, and it counts the number of H and T. I consider the coin has no memory, and the probability to get T is always 1/2

Answer (score 1):

The probability of the next toss being heads is $1/2$. Coin tosses are what we call independent, meaning that if I toss the coin at different times, then the outcome of one trial won't affect the other. You have, however, hit on one of the oddities of conditional probability that a very unlikely event like "my friend got 101 heads in a row" seems on its face very unlikely (a $2^{-101} \approx 3 \cdot 10^{-31}$ chance) is relatively likely given what you already know (that the last 100 tosses were heads). It's irrelevant whether your observations were "consecutive" or not.

For an idea of why your observations on the past probably shouldn't matter, consider the following thought experiment: You're at the casino and you just sat down at a blackjack table. There's one other guy at the table. Do you bother to ask him how he's been doing? Well, if you're a perfect sociopath who doesn't care about etiquette, then no, you probably don't. Maybe he's been on a hot streak. Maybe he's been having awful luck. But that makes no difference to you. After all, whatever kind of night he's been having, the dealer just put the cards back in the shuffler and dealt a new hand. Whatever may've happened before is irrelevant. That is, of course, assuming that you trust the shuffler to be fair, but you said in your question that "it’s guaranteed the coin is perfectly balanced," so that seems apropos.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you better explain to me why the probability of a Head after 100 consecutive Heads is 2**-101 but if the first 100 Heads are not consecutive I shouldn’t care about the past? I do in the first case

Comment: A Head after 100 consecutive Heads is 2^-101 ...  yes and no. If the first 100 tosses are known to be all Heads, the probability to obtain one more Head  is 1/2. If you have not started your tosses, the probability to obtain 100 Heads, plus one more Head is $2^{-101}$.  The probability to obtain HTHTHTHTHTHTHTH....HTH is also $2^{-101}$ ; it is $2^{-101}$ for any sequence of 101 letters.

Comment: @GiuseppeCrinò The point is that when you’re predicting the outcome of the next coin flip, the past is irrelevant. Each coin toss is independent. Consecutive or not, the history has no bearing on what comes next.

Comment: @AJY Makes sense. But why the event of flipping a coin and getting 5 Heads in a row is less likely than other configurations? Can you help me reconcile this fact with the (obviously true) idea that a coin doesn’t have memory?

Comment: @GiuseppeCrinò If you flip a coin 5 times, the odds of all of those coming out heads is $2^{-5} = 3.125 \%$. There are other more likely outcomes, e.g. 2 heads and 3 tails is $\binom{5}{2} \cdot 2^{-5} = 5/16 = 31.25 \%$. But the distinction here is about conditional probability and how it can conflict with our intuition. If my friend tells me that he flipped heads 100 times in a row, then I'll be incredulous. But if I could somehow verify those 100 consecutive heads, and he then flipped heads one more time, then I *should* say, "Eh, that's not too crazy. 50/50 chance, after all."